# How to handle tap in UITextView without losing default tap handle event

Tags: objective-c, uitextview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am using a TapGestureRecognizer to  intercept single taps on a UITextView. However, this single tap makes the default single tap event not happen. Normally, without the personalized gesture recognizer I am inserting, the default tap makes the keyboard appear or the menu (cut/copy/paste/...) appear, depending on the circumstances.

I've already seen some apps in which there is an event fired after a tap in the UITextView besides the default event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `[textField becomeFirstResponder]` to your custom logic. This will bring up the keyboard for the textfield the same way it would if it was tapped normally.

Comment: This exactly what is what I needed, but it sent me immediately to another issue: the tap gesture recognizer I implemented does not respond any more to the tap after the textField became first responder.

Comment: did you add functionality for the textField to `resignFirstResponder` as well?

Comment: I'll explain: when the UITextView is tapped for the first time, nothing should happen, it just has to get the focus. Thats what happens now that I added the becomeFirstResponder line. The conditions inside the gesture recognizer selector are already set so that nothing happens when a title bar is visible. When I start editing the text, the bar gets hidden and this is when I need the next tap to take effect. As you can see, the UITextView should not ever change its normal behavior, but it should also recognize personalized taps. If I use the resignFirstResponder, I think it will lose its focus